# How do I create a constantly updated textarea in PHP using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

My plan is to have one big textarea that needs no submit button to update it, each time you enter a character it will be saved and show on another user's computer in real time.

I have no idea how to do this. Could anyone please help?

I have some code I could share but honestly it's not worth it, it'd be easier if someone could just point me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: sounds like a chat application

Comment: Ahhh... my answer didn't think about a possible chat application!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have an `on (keyUp` function calling a php file by ajax to save the textarea contents to a database or file (database preferably). This is the capture portion complete.

For your 'monitoring' station is a little easier. A textarea with a jquery function polling the database (via another ajax call) to populate a div or other textarea. Setting the jquery interval short enough can resemble real-time. Don't set it too short otherwise you will needlessly bog down the web server with requests.

Can I ask why real-time is a requirement?

Comment: It's not a requirement, something close will do. Thank you for the help.

Comment: If it is a chat application there are a number of prefabricated plugins and libraries on the net

Comment: Okay, I'll do some searching. Do you also know anyway I could allow only a certain amount of characters to be changed from one user every so often?

Comment: Very difficult because of the number of ways you can change text in a textarea - backspace, delete, select multiple characters with mouse and start typing (will replace selected text) etc. What you're attempting may be better implemented with a bespoke application...